# Ruby Guard ignore files

Tags: ruby, guard

I would like to run the requirejs optimization script when any `.js` file is changed (except for `built.js`).

I read there is an ignore method. I have the following in my `Gaurdfile` (which is causing an infinite loop).

```
guard 'shell', :ignore => 'built.js' do
  watch(/script\/(.*).js/) { `node r.js -o build.js` }
end
```

My question is: How do I configure my `Guardfile` to ignore the file `built.js`?

Comment: If you just totally want to ignore built.js, put that at the top of the file (potentially with filter), like you see in the documentation: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples . For more info on filter (to only consider .js files) refer to the documentation here: https://github.com/guard/guard#filter. For syntax of guard-shell, here: https://github.com/guard/guard-shell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, assuming you already have the guard-shell gem installed...

I think this gives you something to work from given what you are trying to do.
It will ignore the script/build.js file and trigger a shell command when any other .js file changes.

```
ignore /script\/build.js/

guard :shell do
  watch /.*\.js/ do |m|
    `yourcommandhere`
    msg = "Processed #{m[0]}"
    n msg, 'mycustomshellcommand'
    "-> #{msg}"
  end
end
```

[See this link for Guardfile examples](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples). 
[See this link for the syntax of guard-shell](https://github.com/guard/guard-shell).